# Docker mountpoint permission setup at runtime

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to create a Docker image that can read host data in a mount point at runtime, the program is writing in this same place too, but i'm facing issue concerning user permission, in the container and when the host is trying to access "container created" files.

This is run periodically so it's not a service nor run by docker-compose

I've some requirements that I must fulfill:

- Non-root access on host
- Non-root access on container except at buildtime
- Host must have permissions on the documents created by the container
- Will be run in production

I've figured how to change GID/UID at buildtime but it's not what I need since I don't want to re-build the image on each system, I need a runtime solution.

I've seen some posts here but they are old and look more like hacks than a real solution.

Here's the command I'm currently running:

```
docker run \
-it \
--env MONGO_STORAGE_PORT \
--env MONGO_STORAGE_HOST \
--env MONGO_STORAGE_DB \
--env MONGO_STORAGE_USER \
--env MONGO_STORAGE_PASSWORD \
--env TZ \
-v $DATA_PATH:$PIPELINE_DATA_PATH:rw \ <--- Here is the concerned mountpoint
--network ${STACK_ENV}-mongo-network \
my_image:${VERSION} \
python3.8 /pipeline/src/pipeline.py
```

Comment: Why not run the script directly on the host?  You probably already have Python available, you don't need to be root (either on the host or in the container), and filesystem permissions will be enforced normally without doing any special setup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is already working properly on "local" host as you assume, but there is other tasks running on other host that can create conflict with some of the dependancies of this project

Comment: You can use a [Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) to get an isolated installation tree for a Python application, without the hard isolation Docker introduces (the program still runs directly on the host, just with a different Python library tree).

Comment: I was talking about system dependencies but I understand that it'll be the easiest way to solve my problem, but it's more a workaround to solve the problem than a solution using docker.

I will stay on the host if I can't find a solution but do you think this is even possible regarding my requirement, using Docker ?
Thanks again